# Subscribe to every topic partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka

What is the canonical way to subscribe multiple times to a given Kafka topic and receive every message from every partition for each `KafkaConsumer`.

What I am doing as the moment is generating a random Uuid `group.id` so that each subscription is a new group, but given these subscriptions are short-lived (and there are many of them), the overhead of Kafka storing metadata about them might be detrimental.

What is the correct way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to this question is to use the `assign()` method rather than `subscribe()`.

> Manual topic assignment through this method does not use the
> consumer's group management functionality.

Reference: https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, having unique consumer groups is the way to ensure that your consumer(s) running inside a group subscribes to all partitions and receives all the messages. That is the purpose of multiple consumer group subscribing to the same topic.

I agree that it requires you to create multiple consumer groups and that gives the overhead of metadata. But it all depends on your usecase requirement whether you want single/multiple consumer groups.

Comment: If there are say 100 subscriptions in a day. That's 100 KafkaConsumer's with unique group.ids....do these ever get cleaned up, or will this list grow by 100 each day?

Comment: No, those are not auto cleaned up. You can delete a group only when there is no active consumer. An option is that you can reset the offsets and reuse the same or otherwise delete the consumer groups everyday.  Are you sure, you want to recreate new group-ids everyday?

Comment: They are cleaned... The offsets topic has defined retention settings